# Magento 2 adding extra step whithin checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment

I have made extra step in between shipping and payment steps by using KO. Now I want to add some logic in HTML file and for that I want to run php code so that I can call my model to check my module is active or not that I can easily do in PHTML. Any good suggestion what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

**Add the JavaScript file implementing the new step**

A new checkout step must be implemented as UI component. That is, its JavaScript implementation must be a JavaScript module.

The file must be stored under the /view/frontend/web/js/view directory.

A sample my-step-view.js with comments follows:

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
],
function (
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    stepNavigator
) {
    'use strict';
    /**
    *
    * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template, 
    * <Vendor>_<Module>  - is the name of the your module directory.
    * 
    */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: '<Vendor>_<Module>/mystep'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(true),

        /**
        *
        * @returns {*}
        */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                'step_code',
                //step alias
                null,
                //step title value
                'Step Title',
                //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                * sort order value
                * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                */
                15
            );

            return this;
        },

        /**
        * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
        * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
        * for switching to your custom step 
        */
        navigate: function () {

        },

        /**
        * @returns void
        */
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    });
}
```

);

**Add the .html template**

In the module directory, add the .html template for the component. It must be located under the /view/frontend/web/template directory.

A sample mystep.html follows:

```
<!--The 'step_code' value from the .js file should be used-->
```

```
<div id="checkout-step-title"
     class="step-content"
     data-role="content">

    <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Add your step to the Checkout page layout**

For the new step to be displayed on the page, you need to declare it in the Checkout page layout, which is defined in checkout_index_index.xml.

So you need to add an extending checkout_index_index.xml layout file in the following location: /view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

A sample checkout_index_index.xml follows:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <!-- The new step you add -->
                                        <item name="my-new-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">%Vendor%_%Module%/js/view/my-step-view</item>
                                                <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
                                                <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
                                                <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder" > 2 -->
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

And in last run

```
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```